# Ternary operator in C# to look code cleaner

Tags: c#, ternary-operator

I am sorry for asking this stupid question.

I know that ternary operator has made developers' life very easy. I have a question in my mind.

Suppose I have to check whether something is `DBNull.Value` or not, if it is then assign '0' or keep the value as it is. I do this like below

```
string str = dt.Rows["Col"] == DBNull.Value ? "0" : dt.Rows["Col"].ToString():
```

It works fine but if my expression is big then it results ugly code like

```
int CL = (int)Math.Round((Convert.ToInt32(dtByType.Compute("sum(NumberOfLeaves)", "Type = 'Casual Leave (Percent)'") == DBNull.Value ? 0 : dtByType.Compute("sum(NumberOfLeaves)", "Type = 'Casual Leave (Percent)'")) * Total_Leaves) / 100d);
```

look at repetition of code in that. Can I make it look little simpler.

I know `??`  is a cleaner way to check for `null` is there anything for `DBNull.Value` or "" ?

Thanks

Comment: If it becomes too complicated (happens to all of us), resort to if-statements. People who will manage your code after you will be thankful.

Comment: I would suggest using multible named variables. I.e. saving the string for the `Convert.ToInt32` in a variable and have your ternary operator there

Comment: You should use the `if-else` statement .. it will increase readability of the code

Comment: Not real question. Not understanding what are you expecting as a answer

Comment: Currently your approach does not even compile because 1. `dt.Rows["Col"]` (Rows accepts an int) and 2. `DBNull.Value ? 0 : dt.Rows["Col"].ToString()` because 0 is an `int` as opposed to  `dt.Rows["Col"].ToString()`

Comment: I would probably write some extension methods like `GetValueOrDefault` for DataRow or `ComputeOrDefault` for `DataTable`.

Comment: why people finding my innocent question so offensive :'( downvotes :'(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used extension method for that. Thanks to `mike z` for the comment :)

```
public static class Extensions
    {
        public static object DefaultIfDBNull(this object obj, object _default)
        {
            return obj == DBNull.Value ? _default : obj;
        }
    }
```

and calling code

```
int CL = (int)Math.Round((Convert.ToInt32(dtByType.Compute("sum(NumberOfLeaves)", "Type = 'Casual Leave (Percent)'").DefaultIfDBNull(0)) * Total_Leaves) / 100d);
```

though it is not a proper answer but it make it cleaner and usable :)

Comment: What makes it "not a proper answer"?

Comment: As asked, Is there any operator kind of thing for that? but there is nothing like this. No question has no answer but to simplify logic :)

Answer (score 0):

> Can I make it look little simpler.

Yes, at the minute your method checks if compute is null and then returns 0 if it is so you can start by extracting the common method

```
var computed = dtByType.Compute("sum(NumberOfLeaves)", "Type = 'Casual Leave (Percent)'");
int CL = (int)Math.Round((Convert.ToInt32(computed == DBNull.Value ? 0 : computed) * Total_Leaves) / 100d)
```

But you can go further by putting this into a method and then just returning 0 if it is null

```
private int GetComputed(int Total_Leaves)
{
     var computed = dtByType.Compute("sum(NumberOfLeaves)", "Type = 'Casual Leave (Percent)'");
     if(computed == DBNull.Value)
          return 0;
     return (int)Math.Round(Convert.ToInt32(computed) * Total_Leaves) / 100d;
}
```

Comment: I wanted this in the core of extension method not in C#. It doesn't exist. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: @Imad - I didn't understand your comment. If you are saying you were wondering if there was a C# operator, then no, but the answer is to simplify your logic

Answer (score 0):

You could wrap the test in a simple method something like the following:

```
public static string GetString(Object testObject)
{
   return testObject == DBNull.Value ? "0" : testObject.ToString();
}
```

Its basically the same but you don't have your ternary test all over the place.

Your code would be something like:

```
(int)Math.Round((Convert.ToInt32(GetString(dtByType.Compute("sum(NumberOfLeaves)", "Type = 'Casual Leave (Percent)'"))) * Total_Leaves) / 100d);
```

It requires you to convert the string result though - so not a perfect solution for all cases.